# Phonegap is only for mobile development

Tags: cordova, mobile, phonegap-build

can i develop desktop application for windows platform using phonegap. Is phonegap is only for mobile development..? Please help me to figure it out

and

How can i install windows mobile apps in windows desktop version. I know the installation file format is different. Any option to run apps independently without the help of any emulator or software. Is there any possibilities to create application for windows mobile and PC on a single code base

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is built for accessing mobile specific things like camera, contact list  like device properties from Javascript. PhoneGap  cannot do this functionalities in windows desktop application.

Comment: How can i install windows mobile apps in windows desktop version. I know the installation file format is different. Any option to run apps **independently** without the help of any emulator or software. Is there **any possibilities to create application for windows mobile and PC on a single code base**

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap is basically meant to use the web technologies to build a mobile native app. As far as I know it does not work on desktop OSes. However you can try out the Node-Webkit which is kind of similar framework and helps you to develop Native Desktop apps with Web Technologies.

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/

Here are some of the apps developed with Node-Webkit

https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/List-of-apps-and-companies-using-nw.js

If you have developed a mobile app using PhoneGap, I think with some refactoring you should be able to use the same codebase to create a Node-Webkit app. Though the changes may differ from app to app, but you can still give it a try.

Comment: thaks a lot... anyway i ll give a try using node-webkit

Answer (score 0):

You can use phonegap/cordova local development to create windows 8/8.1 and even windows 10 apps

[See the platform guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_win8_index.md.html#Windows%20Platform%20Guide)

But phonegap build service doesn't support windows apps yet.